# Code Signing error Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: xxx (5Wxxx)' appears more than once in the keychain... but no duplication

Tags: xcode, provisioning, keychain, certificate, profiles

I have 2 sets of identity, one for me, one for a team I'm on (for a client). Therefore, 2 "iPhone Developer: (5W...) and iPhone Developer (7E...) keys and certificates.

In all of the isolated tests I've done, I have only seen the duplicated certificate once (of 2 hrs of troubleshooting). I have seen, when I drop down in build settings on the "code signing", 3 profiles that are "Identities without provisioning profiles". Wondering if it's one of these lingering keys that is the problem.

I'm getting the error since I upgraded to 4.3.3, and since I've tried to run on my device. Oddly, creating an IPA with a distribution profile (team provisioning, for a client) is OK.  Also, no issues with my other iPhone Developer keys & certs (so far).

Read up the other SO posts, and did the fixes, but still not fixed. I've done:

- in Key Chain access, deleted, and re-installed certificate again from Member Center
- cleaned Xcode-Organizer of all profiles, quit both Keychain and Xcode, drag in just the 2 (distrib/dev) in question.
- move the certificates to new keychain, add flag in code signing
- delete derived data, quit both keychain & Xcode, launch, test
- update all expired profiles and certs, in member center and in Organizer

Ideas?

Comment: And before someone says it's a duplicate SO post- it's not! I've read all the other posts, and the unique thing here is that I don't see the "duplicate certificate" that the error is complaining of. All the other SO posts do see the duplicate cert.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I did have a duplicate key (not certificate) in my KeyChain. Thanks to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376587/830304

I looked for keys in other folders, and backed up and deleted the private one. It's hard, because they're basically all named the same thing. But a big tip-off was that this key didn't have a folder-expanding icon, so it wasn't associated with a live/valid certificate.