# Certificate identity 'iPhone Developer: appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one

Tags: iphone, keychain

I deleted old certificate. But  again and again this error will come. But in keychain i have only one certificate. Im using ios6.1

Comment: See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932522/codesign-error-certificate-identity-appearing-twice

Comment: I already saw so many links..won't help...

Comment: close your XCode & also your mac after some time restart it & then check.

Comment: See this & follow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359239/code-sign-error-certificate-identity-iphone-developer-my-name-xxx-appears

Comment: @Vishal: I tried all methods...no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once remove all copy of Your certificate from your keychain, then again install it in keychain. it'll solve your problem.

hope this helps. thanks.

Comment: have u checked Organizer section in your xcode? Have it displaying multiple copy of your certi?

Comment: That's BS that we have to even do this. I'm getting this problem too...easy to solve, but annoying. Because it happens repeatedly. I only got it once I updated to mountain lion

Answer (score 4):

By following @CleverCoder's answer of [Codesign error: Certificate identity appearing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932522/codesign-error-certificate-identity-appearing-twice), I found that just deleting the private key (by clicking the left triangle of the Certification) instead of Certification in "Keychain Access" works for me.

[image]